# Compute the transformation in the given Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

I forgot how to compute the transformation in a given basis. :'(

For example, say I have the transformation \begin{equation}(a, b) \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}10a - 6b \\ 17b - 10b \end{bmatrix}.\end{equation}

The basis in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is made up of the vectors $(1, 2)$ and $(2, 3)$.

What's the procedure again?

Comment: Are you saying that $$T={a\choose b}\to{{10a-6b}\choose{17b-10b}}$$ is a transformation defined in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for the standard basis and you want to know the equivalent transformation in the basis $B=\{{1\choose2},{2\choose3}\}$?

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely the transformation. Im not sure if it's a typo. It's asking to compute the given transformation in respect to some basis B and determine if beta(the two vectors above) which are supposed to be an ordered basis consisting of eigenvectors of the following linear operator T on a vector space. I think I can do the last part by myself, but it's the transformation in respect to B that's bothering me.

Answer (score 1):

For one, I am assuming you meant $17a - 10b$ for the second entry.

The transformation in terms of a given basis is just the image of that basis when written in standard coordinates.

Then, if I read this correctly, $(1,0)^{T} \rightarrow (10, 17)^{T}$ and $(0,1)^{T} \rightarrow (-6,  -10)^{T}$ so that the image of the basis $\{\left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 2 \end{array} \right),\left( \begin{array}{c} 2 \\ 3 \end{array} \right)\}$ is $\{\left( \begin{array}{c} -2 \\ -3 \end{array} \right),\left( \begin{array}{c} 2 \\ 4 \end{array} \right)\}$ making $\left( \begin{array}{cc} -2 & 2 \\ -3 &4 \end{array} \right)$ the matrix representing the transformation in terms of the basis given.

Comment: na, it's 17b - 10b. I thought it was weird too. Not sure if it's a typo